# JPA - Persisting a Unidirectional One to Many relationship fails with EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm trying to persist a very simple Unidirectional One to Many relationship, but EclipseLink (2.3.1) fails.

Service Class (Parent):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_service2")
public class Service implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="service_id")
    public long serviceID;

    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="service_id")
    public Set<Parameter> parameters;
}
```

Parameter Class (Child):
(Of course there is "service_id" foreign key field in the database, which is not represented in the class, as it's unidirectional relation).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_service_parameters2")
public class Parameter implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="param_id")
    public long parameterID;

    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;
}
```

And this is the code for Entity persistence:

```
    Service service = new Service();
    service.parameters = new HashSet<Parameter>();
    service.name = "test";
    Parameter param = new Parameter();
    param.name = "test";
    service.parameters.add(param);
    em.persist(service);
    em.flush();
```

I get this exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'service_id' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO tbl_service_parameters2 (name) VALUES (?)
    bind => [test]
```

**EDIT:** The database field `service_id` has (and should have) not-null constraint, due the nature of the data.

Is this a bug or is something wrong in the code?

Comment: Bizarre. Have you tried a newer version of EclipseLink? 2.3.3 perhaps? Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: @TimBedner Tested also on 2.3.3 and 2.4.0 but no luck. I opened a case at [EclipseLink Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391279)

Comment: Your code looks just fine. Would you like to give it a shot using Batoo JPA? I may provide help if it fails. http://batoo.jp

Comment: I have added the first community test case to Batoo JPA :)
Your case passes... 

https://github.com/BatooOrg/BatooJPA/tree/master/community/src/test/java/org/batoo/jpa/community/test/t1

Comment: I suggest to move the mapping relation to the Parameter class.

 @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="service_id")
private Service service;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try removing the not null constraint on the Parameter table's service_id field.  Eclipselink will update the foreign key for unidirectional 1:m join columns in a separate statement, so you'll need to disable or delay the constraint check.  Making it bidirectional will allow the fp field to be updated with the rest of the parameter data.

Comment: Is the assumption that the OP is manually creating the tables? I assumed table creation was being delegated to EclipseLink as well.

Comment: There is no not null annotation on the relation, so DDL gen wouldnt add one.

Comment: Tables were created manually, therefore not-null constraint is not relevant AFAIN. Making the relation bidirectional does work, but it's a workaround and not answering the question.

Comment: If there isn't a not-null constraint, why the exception for service_id not having a value?  If you remove the constraint, you will see EclipseLink updates the fk later because it is not controlled ny the Parameter entity.

Comment: There is not-null constraint. I'm sorry it wasn't clear from the question but I didn't understand why it's relevant. After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755380 I realized it might be part of the answer...

Comment: This is EclipseLink limitation/bug. Removing the not-null constraint or making the relation bidirectional workarounds it. I'm granting the reward to Chris for helping clarifying this issue. Full details may be found [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391279) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392450)

Comment: This solution helped solve my issue. Had to remove null=false on the foreign key property in my entity object.

Answer (score 41):

Use `nullable = false`, on `@JoinColumn`:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "service_id", nullable = false)
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, as it doesn't change almost any of the premises of the original question.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem without changing anything else.

Answer (score 2):

By default nullable is true on @JoinColumn, while persisting the data in one to  many relationship, we need to make nullable as false to avoid data violation exceptions that occurs at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your persistence for hibernate version<4.0 and your code will run well."Well" in reference " for one-to-many relation save/persist parent ONLY, NOT save/persist child's collection by separate task"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work in Oracle by using a deferrable foreign key.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (my_table_column) REFERENCES foreign_key_table  (foreign_key_table_column) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, in such cases, foreign key is filled in a separate statement. In my example, I used `Address` entity with `customer_id` as foreign key.

```
2014-07-08T20:51:12.752+0300|FINE: INSERT INTO ADDRESS (address_id, street, city, region) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [10, foo, foo, foo]
2014-07-08T20:51:12.753+0300|FINEST: Execute query InsertObjectQuery(ua.test.customer.Address@28cef39d)
2014-07-08T20:51:12.757+0300|FINEST: Execute query DataModifyQuery(sql="UPDATE ADDRESS SET customer_id = ? WHERE (address_id = ?)")
2014-07-08T20:51:12.757+0300|FINE: UPDATE ADDRESS SET customer_id = ? WHERE (address_id = ?)
    bind => [151, 10]
```

Therefore, having `@JoinColumn` with `nullable=true` causes an error.

As alternative, you can use `@OneToMany (..., orphanRemoval = true, ...)`.