# JPA Eclipselink error: "Field 'Target_id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'll try to be as short & objective as possible. I'm using JPA Eclipselink 2.5.2. After creating my database with a MySQL script, I'm trying to populate it. Compilation is giving me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'Target_id' doesn't have a
>   default value Error Code: 1364 Call: INSERT INTO TARGET (32_bit_arch,
>   IP, Name, Operating_system) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)   bind => [true,
>   127.0.0.1, Intel i7 2.6 Ghz + 8 GB, CentOS 6.5 32 bit]

I've searched all over both SO and Google, but even when I find a similar situation (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755380/jpa-persisting-a-unidirectional-one-to-many-relationship-fails-with-eclipselin)), the solutions doesn't seem to work (removing the not null constraints with @JoinColumn(nullable = false) or appplying @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true), etc). Relevant information goes below:

**1. MySQL table creation script:**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `fault_injector`.`Target`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fault_injector`.`Target` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fault_injector`.`Target` (
  `Target_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `32_bit_arch` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `IP` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Operating_system` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Target_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idTarget_UNIQUE` (`Target_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `IP_UNIQUE` (`IP` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `fault_injector`.`Experiment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fault_injector`.`Experiment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fault_injector`.`Experiment` (
  `Exp_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Creator_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Target_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Creation_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `Injection_date` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `Description` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Exp_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Experiment_id_UNIQUE` (`Exp_id` ASC),
  INDEX `Target_id_idx` (`Target_id` ASC),
  INDEX `User_id_idx` (`Creator_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Experiment_User_id_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Creator_id`)
    REFERENCES `fault_injector`.`User` (`User_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Experiment_Target_id_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Target_id`)
    REFERENCES `fault_injector`.`Target` (`Target_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**2. Target entity:**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Target.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Target t")
public class Target implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Target_id")
    private int target_id;

    [...]

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Experiment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="target")
    private List<Experiment> experiments;

    [...]

    public List<Experiment> getExperiments()
    {
        if(this.experiments==null)
            this.experiments = new ArrayList<Experiment>();

        return this.experiments;
    }

    public Experiment addExperiment(Experiment experiment) {
        getExperiments().add(experiment);
        experiment.setTarget(this);

        return experiment;
    }
```

**3. Experiment entity:**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Experiment.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Experiment    e")
public class Experiment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Exp_id")
    private int exp_id;

    [...]

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Target
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="Target_id")
    private Target target;

    [...]

    public void setTarget(Target target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
```

**4. Code**

Although the compiler says the error occurs when the entity manager is calling flush (`em.flush();`), I know that other line is related to the error, because if I comment it the error simply goes away: `target.addExperiment(experiment);` (please note that both target and experiment are instances of the entities with the same name - if needed, I can post more code, but for now I'm trying to make the question not (so) long). So it seems the problem is on the bi-directional association between Target and Experiment, but apart from that, I'm stucked with this error.

Comment: So, what is the code causing the exception? Did you set the target of the experiment to a non-null value? Also, the compiler compiles tha Java code. It doesn't run it.

Comment: Yes, the compiler doesn't run the code, it just compiles it, it was an unfortunate sentence of mine. Regarding the problem itself, it turned out that it must have been Eclipse messing up after consecutive hours of trial & error. Today it didn't give any error, and the data is on the database, I've already checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the table definition in your database, e.g.

```
describe target
```

I guess, it is different from the `create table` statement, you have shown in the question. Especially, the definition for column `target_id` might be not shown as `auto_increment`.

Depending on the definition of `target_id`, you could modify the column with

```
alter table target modify column target_id int not null auto_increment;
```

Comment: It turned out that it must have been Eclipse messing up after consecutive hours of trial & error. Today it didn't give any error, and the data is on the database, I've already checked it.

By the way, `describe target` predictably returned `auto_increment`. Thank you all for your help.