# Cascade ALL doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, orm, one-to-many, cascade

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQUENCE_UID", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
   private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>(); 
   ...
   ...

   public List<Page> getPages() {
     return Collections.unmodifiableList(pages);
   }

   public void add(Page page){
      this.pages.add(page);
   }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGES")
public class Page {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQUENCE_UID", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "COLOR", nullable = false)
   private String color;

   ...
   ...
}
```

As you can see I'm using CascadeType.ALL on the pages list and indeed, when I'm trying to create a new Book, I can see the following query:

```
INSERT INTO PAGES (ID, COLOR) VALUES (?,?)
```

But then I get this exception:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "book_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I'm using EclipseLink and Spring-Data and this is how I'm creating a new Book:

```
Page page = new Page();
page.setColor("RED");
Book book = new Book();
book.add(page);
bookRepository.save(book);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `@JoinColumn(..., nullable = false)`.

Comment: But the exception suggests that the value is indeed 'null' and I want it to be not-null... I want the book_id to be set on the page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant nullable = false.

Comment: Just tried this - didn't solve the problem

Comment: Then I don't know. This would work fine in Hibernate, AFAIK, and I don't use EclipseLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755380/jpa-persisting-a-unidirectional-one-to-many-relationship-fails-with-eclipselin) answer - and indeed there seems to be two queries so the not-null did prevent the second one.

Comment: Having said that... I don't want this 'wrong' definition to stay - I mean, the fact that the book_id column on the Page can be null is unacceptable since a page without a book is useless sine no one reads a page - ones reads a book (it might have a single page but it is a valid setup) - is there another solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is both classes don't generate their id automatically, so you see the error

> ERROR: null value in column "book_id" violates not-null constraint

JPA Entity objects need not null **id** on persists. You can set the is manually:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setId(1L);
bookRepository.save(book);
```

But is more easy use a generated value strategic:

```
 @Entity 
 @Table(name = "BOOKS")
 public class Book {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BOOK_SEQ")
   @SequenceGenerator(name="BOOK_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1, sequenceName="BOOK_SEQ")
   private Long id;

   ...
   ...
 }

 @Entity 
 @Table(name = "PAGES")
 public class Page {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PAGE_SEQ")
   @SequenceGenerator(name="PAGE_SEQ", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1, sequenceName="PAGE_SEQ")
   private Long id;
   ...
   ...
 }
```

**Aditionally you need to create the BOOK_SEQ and PAGE_SEQ on the database, depending of the database the sql script can change, not all databases have sequences, mysql for example don't support sequence**

If you use postgresql for example you can exec the code:

> create sequence BOOK_SEQ
>     start with 1
>     increment by 1
>     maxvalue 10000
>     minvalue 1
>     cycle;
>    create sequence PAGE_SEQ
>     start with 1
>     increment by 1
>     maxvalue 10000
>     minvalue 1
>     cycle;

Comment: Thanks - but I have in my code the following (I didn't mention it in the question though... my bad) @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQUENCE_UID", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Comment: When you persist entities on cascade mode the first object persisted is the principal entity, in your case the Book class then child entities (Page class). Your exception indicates that can't persist Book entity so the problem is not in the OneToMany relation, the problem is that Book object don't have any value on Id, you can set id manually or use any generated strategie value.

Comment: check the answer change

Comment: Are you using hibernate? and what database are you using?

Comment: @CarlosE.FeriaVila read the question: it says that the OP uses eclipselink, and it says that the error is produced by the query `INSERT INTO PAGES (ID, COLOR)`. So it is produced when inserting the page, not the book.